# Permissions Error: Within a python script, I need to find a server file in unix system and open it to run commands for the user

Tags: python, unix, permissions, terminal, subprocess

In a Unix system, within a python script, I am trying to open a terminal window and start a server. It is my understanding that python has a subprocess module that is supposed to allow such a thing. So:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['path to terminal'])
```

returns:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

How do I run this with the right permissions? Or, is there a better, secure way to do what I need?

I'm relatively new to programming, so please reorient the discussion if my question is misguided. Thank you!

Comment: What are the permissions on `'path to terminal'`? That is, what do you see if you type `ls -l 'path to terminal'`?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized now that this is what Johan was asking for: `drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  272 Feb  3 16:50 Contents/`

Comment: The answer is root permissions.

Comment: Er, you're misreading that. `root` is just the owner of the directory. The permissions are `rwxr-xr-x`, which means (among other things) that all users can read and "execute" it. But this does tell you what your problem is: `'path to terminal'` is a directory -- a folder -- rather than a program. So naturally you can't run it.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The conclusion confuses me, how can /Terminal.app be a folder?

Comment: I'm just going based on what you posted. You said that `ls -l 'path to terminal'` produced `drwxr-xr-x 8 root wheel 272 Feb 3 16:50 Contents/`. That implies, firstly, that `'path to terminal'` is `Contents/`, and secondly, that `Contents/` is a folder. (I'm guessing you simply posted the output from the wrong command, or something like that.)

Comment: I'm not trying to contradict you. I'm just confused. I didn't post the wrong command. Here is what I put into the terminal and what resulted: `In [18]: ls -l '/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app'
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  272 Feb  3 16:50 Contents/` Thanks again for your helpfulness.

Comment: What you just posted looks like the output of bare `ls -l`, without any further arguments: that is, it looks like it's showing you the contents of the current directory. Try running `ls -l /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app` this time, without the single-quotes. (The single-quotes would be fine in Bash, but it looks like you're running this in a different environment?)

Comment: Yeah, I was. I tried it in a strait terminal now. This was the result: `drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  272 Feb  3 16:50 Contents` ... looks like all that changed is the `Contents/`

Comment: That's strange. What do you get if you run `ls -ld /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`?

Comment: I get: `drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Feb  3 16:53 /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`

Comment: Yup, I thought you might get that. So `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`, despite its file-like name, *is* a directory. It contains a single file, `Contents`, which is itself a directory.

Comment: I don't understand computers enough to understand yet. So, how do I start this thing from a python script? Here are the contents of the directory, "Contents": `Info.plist PkgInfo _CodeSignature MacOS  Resources version.plist`

Comment: All I want is a way to open another terminal window from within a python script.

Comment: Thanks again ruakh, very helpful. I've asked Johan to +1 you, because I can't yet.

Comment: You're welcome. And there's no need to +1 me -- I've actually already +1'd Johan's answer. (And I don't think he actually needed my analysis. He's clearly familiar with OSX, and apparently recognized the problem as soon as he saw that your command was `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: you state that you would like to execute `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`, so you are apparently running Mac OS X.

Mac OS X .app programs *are* directories. They can be started with the Mac OS shell command `open`.

To open the program /path/to/server in a fresh Max OS Terminal session:

```
import subprocess
termapp=['open','-a','/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app']
sp=subprocess.Popen(termapp+['/path/to/server'])
```

There's also a shell-command version of the terminal, so you do not need `open -a`.

```
import subprocess
termapp=['/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal']
sp=subprocess.Popen(termapp+['/path/to/server'])
```

The two ways have subtle differences in how the windows are grouped by the window manager. Each time you do the above you get another terminal process and another icon in the tray. While with -a a new window is opened within the same Terminal main program.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here is the path to the terminal I need: `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`
 I tried your above suggestion, this is what I got: 

    In [67]: subprocess.Popen(['bash /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app'], shell=True)
    Out[67]: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x12945f0>
    In [68]: /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app: /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app: is a directory

Comment: Don't know whether this would solve OP's problem, but using `shell=True` is really bad due to security reasons. Using `subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'])` and like is [highly recommended](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. If I had 15 votes I would +1 you and ruakh. Johan, is it possible for you to +1 ruakh? He helped you find the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @MikeHalpin, good. Only up voted answers (not comments) give credit to the poster so there's nothing more I can +1.